# Exectly when is Observable.unsubscribeOn() called/when is a Observable unsubscribed while using Observable.unsubscribeOn()

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-java2

I was studying the tutorial in [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/141980/rxandroid-tutorial) link and wrote the following code.

```
public class CheeseActivity extends BaseSearchActivity {
Observable<String> textInput = Observable.create(
        e -> {
            try {
                //emit what the user types in the text field
                String query = mQueryEditText.getText().toString().trim();
                Log.e("myapp", query + " 0");
                e.onNext(query);

                e.onComplete();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                e.onError(ex);
            }
        }
);

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Button searchbtn = mSearchButton;

    searchbtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        textInput
                //show the progressbar in ui thread
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).doOnNext(query -> {
            Log.e("myapp", query + " 1");
            showProgressBar();
        })
                //perform the search in io thread
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io()).map(query -> mCheeseSearchEngine.search(query))
                //show search result in ui thread
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(results -> {
            Log.e("myapp", "search finished");
            hideProgressBar();
            showResult(results);
        });
        Log.e("myapp", "unsubbed");
    });
    textInput.unsubscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

}
}
```

here is the logcat (ch is the string taken from edittext field)

---

E/myapp: ch 0

E/myapp: unsubbed

E/myapp: ch 1

E/myapp: search finished

---

Clearly, "unsubbed" is printed right after button click.
 But i want to print "unsubbed" right after *textInput* Observable is unsubscribed. how do i do it?

Comment: so just use doOnUnsubscribe(). what wrong with that?

Comment: @yosriz there is no Observable.doOnUnsubscribe() in rxjava 2 https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4811

Comment: oh.. I think yo should specify this on your question (you can also add the rx-java2 tag) it's not clear you're referring to rx-java2

Comment: @yosriz i posted the answer,thanks for replying anyway

Answer (score 0):

just learned it 
.doFinally(() -> Log.e("myapp","unsubbed")) just before .subscribe(...)